# When trying to upload EPUB files the FILES and POST vars arrive empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have a working form that Inserts book entries to DB, it takes book title, isbn, book cover, etc.
I currently can upload the book cover and PDF version of the book without any issues, but the moment i try to upload a EPUB file instead of the PDF version, the FILES and POST arrive empty in the controller

-I have tried adding the mime types

```
  'epub' => 'application/epub+zip',
  //'epub' => array('application/octet-stream', 'application/epub+zip','application/smil+xml'),
```

- The input works correctly because if i choose a PDF instead everything runs ok

// The form

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart(base_url().$this->uri->uri_string()); ?>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading"><h6 class="panel-title"><i class="icon-page-break"></i> </h6>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <h5>BOOK INFO</h5>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>title:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" >
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>description:</label>
                        <textarea rows="5" cols="5" name="description" class="form-control"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Cover:</label>
                        <input type="file" class="styled form-control" id="report-screenshot" name="userfile">
                        <span class="help-block">: gif, png, jpg</span>
                    </div>
                    <hr>
                    <h5>
                        FILES
                    </h5>

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>EPUB:</label>
                                <input type="file" class="styled form-control" id="epub_file" name="epub">
                                <span class="help-block">: .EPUB</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>PDF:</label>
                                <input type="file" class="styled form-control" id="pdf_file" name="pdf">
                                <span class="help-block">: .PDF</span>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <hr>
                    <div class="form-actions text-right">
                        <input type="submit" value="Add" class="btn btn-primary">
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>

            <?php echo form_close() ?>
```

// In the controller

```
  var_dump($_FILES); // array (size=0)
  var_dump($_POST); // array (size=0)
```

Comment: Where is the form that handles the uploading part? Can't be of help with a PHP issue if only got an HTML form to look at. :/

Comment: The moment they arrive to the controller everything is empty
 var_dump($_FILES); // array (size=0)
  var_dump($_POST); // array (size=0)

Comment: `print_r($_FILES)` also empty? can't explain it... if it were too large of a file you'd atleast have an error in the files array

Comment: @Alex print_r($_FILES) is also empty, As far as i can tell it seems as if Codeigniter(or something else)  scrubs the post and files array before processing the controller when the uploaded file is .epub.   I have tried digging in the Codeigniter system folder to try to find when but i havent found anything yet

Comment: @Alex !! you were right! it was the file size!!
The POST limit was set to 9mb, 
 the PDF size of the book was 8mb, 
the image was 500kb, 
the EPUB was 9.2 mbs.  
Thats why everything uploaded correctly if i omitted the EPUB, but if i tried uploading the EPUB even on its own it got deleted.  Unfortunately post_max_size_limit didnt throw any warnings.
Would you like to sent it as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 1):

It was the post limit. 
The POST limit was set to 9mb, the PDF size of the book was 8mb, the image was 500kb, the EPUB was 9.2 mbs. Thats why everything uploaded correctly if i omitted the EPUB, but if i tried uploading the EPUB even on its own it got deleted. Unfortunately post_max_size_limit didnt throw any warnings.